# How can I find all the strings that contains "/1" and remove from a file using Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have this file that contains these kinds of strings "1405079/1" the only common in them is the "/1" at the end. I want to be able to find those strings and remove them, below is sample code
but it's not doing anything.

```py
with open("jobstat.txt","r") as jobstat:
    with open("runjob_output.txt", "w") as runjob_output:
        for line in jobstat:
                string_to_replace = ' */1'
                line = line.replace(string_to_replace, " ")
```

Comment: Is it always a number followed by `/1`? Is it always 7 digits long? A regular expression is the best course of action here, probably. Can you share a short example input and the expected output?

Comment: It's always follow by "/1" and No it's not always 7 digits long, it's preceded by a lot of random numbers, the only constant is "/1" at the end. I need to find all the strings that have the "/1" at the end and remove it from the file.

Comment: Is it always numbers? Or letters and numbers? Are there ever spaces or hyphens or anything else? Please post a short, representative example input and the expected output. Your comment below on my solution is also confusing. Do you want to replace these instances with an empty string, as your original post suggests, or "return" them, as you say in your comment below?

Comment: it's always just numbers no hyphens or anything else, in short I have this file(.txt) that contains run numbers that always ends with "/1" so I want to find all those run numbers and remove them from the file, I tried this code "pattern = re.findall(r"\d*\/1", line) and it finds them all but it put them in a list, so then I tried, clearing the list by doing "pattern.clear()" but the numbers still remains in the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("jobstat.txt","r") as jobstat:
    with open("runjob_output.txt", "w") as runjob_output:
        for line in jobstat:
                string_to_replace ='/1' 
                line =line.rstrip(string_to_replace)
                print(line)
```

Comment: This doesn't work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you have a "pattern" you want to match against, use a regular expression. The pattern here, given the information you've provided, is a string with an arbitrary number of digits followed by `/1`.

You can use `re.sub` to match against that pattern, and replace instances of it with another string.

```py
import re

original_string= "some random text with 123456/1, and midd42142/1le of words"

pattern = r"\d*\/1"
replacement = ""

re.sub(pattern, replacement, original_string)
```

Output:

```
'some random text with , and middle of words'
```

Replacing instances of the pattern with something else:

```py
>>>  re.sub(pattern, "foo", original_string)
'some random text with foo, and middfoole of words'
```

Comment: I have a bit of a problem, with the solution above, How can I define the original string in such a way that I will read the file and find and return all strings ending in "/1" because the strings ending in "/1" is preceded by a lot of random numbers?

Comment: "Find and return" is different than "find and remove" which is what your original post asks for. Please update your post with a more accurate problem statement, as well as an example input and expected output.

Comment: sorry It's not actually find and return, it's just find and remove. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: I finally got it! I've used "pattern = re.sub(r"\d*\/1*", "", line)" then write in the output file as "outfile.write(pattern)"  Thank you for the Idea, I knew yours was the closest to what I'm trying to achieve I just had to find a way around it. Thank you so much!